# sending a XAPI-Request to the API-Server - over http

Tags: openstreetmap, cartography, api, xml

pretty new to Geo-Informatics so do not bear with me if my questions sound like newbie-questions: can i do some requests on POIs of Openstreetmap with XAPI.

doing like so: i send a request to the  API-Server - over http 
as a respond i get the following result - in XML

**example:** the following link gives back all the Nodes of the Type amenity=restaurant in XML-Format.Note: the bounding box (bbox) limits the area:

```
http://xapi.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/node[amenity=restaurant][bbox=9.4908142,48.7810801,9.5660019,48.8387351]
```

see here the results:_

```
<?xml version='1.0' standalone='no'?>
<osm version='0.6' generator='xapi: OSM Extended API 2.0' xmlns:xapi='http://www.informationfreeway.org/xapi/0.6' xapi:uri='/api/0.6/node[amenity=restaurant|fast_food|pub|cafe][bbox=9.4908142,48.7810801,9.5660019,48.8387351]' xapi:planetDate='20100824' xapi:copyright='2010 OpenStreetMap contributors' xapi:license='Creative commons CC-BY-SA 2.0' xapi:bugs='For assistance or to report bugs contact 80n80n@gmail.com' xapi:instance='zappyOsm'>
 <node id='721241970' lat='48.830856' lon='9.5116892' user='mabe75' timestamp='2010-05-04T19:01:28Z' uid='260302' version='1' changeset='4607010'>
 <tag k='amenity' v='restaurant'/>
 <tag k='name' v='Lamm'/>
 </node>
 <node id='392682646' lat='48.8315734' lon='9.5468864' user='MattGPS' timestamp='2010-05-11T19:00:20Z' uid='12973' version='3' changeset='4671372'>
 <tag k='amenity' v='restaurant'/>
 <tag k='name' v='Gasthaus an der Wieslauf'/>
 </node>
 <node id='319597380' lat='48.8277913' lon='9.5477029' timestamp='2008-12-17T21:13:15Z' version='1' changeset='444629'>
 <tag k='amenity' v='restaurant'/>
 <tag k='name' v='Gasthaus zur Linde'/>
 </node>
[...]
```

well this example does not work here... what do ido wrong

**update:**

although this page doesn't explicitly say where xapi.opentreetmap.org points to these days, it does say that jxapi.openstreetmap.org (which it might point to) is down for maintenance right now. However, Mapquests's jxapi instance should be up, so we should be able to do that. Well actually i did a try and did just this:

```
wget http://open.mapquestapi.com/xapi/api/0.6/node[amenity=restaurant][bbox=9.4908142,48.7810801,9.5660019,48.8387351]
```

and it works. Note that there's an extra "/api" in the Mapquest xapi URL. The bbox is currently limited to 10 square degrees. See the various links from the XAPI wiki page for more info, including the terms of service for the Mapquest instance of the XAPI.

Any idea how i can delimit the bbox - in order to run over a whole town like Hamburg or Berlin or lemme take Paris for example

**By the way**. How to get the results stored in a databasse- note i have to convert the xml to a db-sheme.. mysql is preferred- any idea and helping hand is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I sometimes find that the official OSM Xapi is not that reliable, indeed it is currently [shown as](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Xapi) being down for maintenance.

You will probably be better off using the Mapquest Open API - url as follows:

[http://open.mapquestapi.com/xapi/api/0.6/node[amenity=restaurant][bbox=9.4908142,48.7810801,9.5660019,48.8387351]](http://open.mapquestapi.com/xapi/api/0.6/node%5Bamenity=restaurant%5D%5Bbbox=9.4908142,48.7810801,9.5660019,48.8387351%5D)

They also have good docs for all parameters.

Comment: hello dear Stev_K  thx for the reply i just did it via wget and it works. How to get the results stored in a databasse- note i have to convert the xml to a db-sheme.. mysql is preferred- any idea and helping hand is greatly appreciated

Comment: postgis is the standard db to which osm xml is imported to. MySQL you are probably on your own: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/MySQL. If you use postgis, use one of the standard import processes. Probably http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis is a good start